# Sequelize - How to bulkCreate with ignoreDuplicates AND return only the inserted items?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been struggling with this... The functionality of bulkCreate w/ ignore duplicates seems to be exactly what I need, but with returning : true, it returns ALL records that attempted insert, I need just the records that were inserted. Thanks!